# upload low quality using youtube api so that upload time is decreased

Tags: android, ios, react-native, youtube, youtube-api

Lets say we are using youtube API inside android mobile app to upload videos straight to YouTube. Is there a way to lower the upload time by lowering the video quality using the API itself? Is it builtin to the youtube api? or shall we use a 3rd party library that will do the downsizing and then pass the downsizing to youtube api? What is the best approach for this?

Comment: I don't believe there is any transcoding going on within the mobile client Youtube API (its just a RESTful API). Remember that lower quality in means that it will look poor on a high res screen/client.

Comment: You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video-processing